# My datagridview, it repeats the same table for 4 times

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview, vba

The datagridview loads:

```
Private Sub omplir_taula()

        obrir_conecció()
        Taula.DataSource = Nothing
        Taula.Rows.Clear()
        Taula.Columns.Clear()

        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Incidencies,Departaments ", myConnection)
        da.Fill(ds, "Incidencies")

        Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view1
        Taula.DataSource = view1
        Taula.Refresh()


    End Sub
```

My problem is the code repeats four times the datatable and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your query:

```
Select * from Incidencies,Departaments
```

This will just combine the two tables, resulting in a [Cartesian product](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm). What you have to do is join the two tables in a proper way.

Example:

```
Table A:
Id=1; name='test1'
Id=2; name='test2'

Table B:
Id=1; fkId=1; item='item1'
Id=2; fkId=2; item='item2'
```

With your query

```
Select * from A,B
```

the result will be:

```
Id=1; name='test1'; Id=1; fkId=1; item='item1'
Id=1; name='test1'; Id=2; fkId=2; item='item2'
Id=2; name='test2'; Id=1; fkId=1; item='item1'
Id=2; name='test2'; Id=2; fkId=2; item='item2'
```

With a join:

```
Select * from A
Inner Join B on A.Id=B.fkId
```

will return:

```
Id=1; name='test1'; Id=1; fkId=1; item='item1'
Id=2; name='test2'; Id=2; fkId=2; item='item2'
```